# Change the colors of subviews with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation

I have a **UISlider** and added some **subviews** in the slider's track successfully. I want to **change the color** of the subviews one by one with **animation**. 
[image]

Comment: do you meant you have 3 slider as RGB combination and want to change the view color when slider is changed?

Comment: No I have a custom slider in which I am adding small views as subview in slider's view..please refer the screen shot. I want to change the color from green to clear color and vice versa with animation

Answer (score 0):

This example may be helpful for you, sorry not completely understand you in first time:

```
typedef void (^VoidBlock)(void);
@interface ClassName ()

@property (nonatomic, strong)VoidBlock animationBlock;

@end

- (void)runAnimation
{    
    NSArray *views = @[view1, view2, view3];

    __weak LibraryViewController *weak_self = self;
    __block NSInteger currentView = 0;  
    __block NSUInteger colorNumber = 0;
    self.animationBlock = ^{
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            if (colorNumber == 0){
                [views[currentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
            }
            else if (colorNumber == 1){
                [views[currentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1]];
            }
            else {
                [views[currentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1]];
            }

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            currentView += 1;
            if (currentView == views.count){
                currentView = 0;                
                colorNumber += 1;
                if (colorNumber == views.count)
                    colorNumber = 0;
            }
            weak_self.animationBlock();
        }];
    };

    self.animationBlock();
}
```

Comment: Sorry have you understood my requirement?

Comment: It is changing the colors of the views in one shot...There is no delay...What I actually want is, second view's color should be changed only after the first view is changed

Comment: Basically the completion block called immediately even though I set the animation duration is 1 sec.

Comment: emm, it is not wright, I ware test it, and it works.